# how to get the best-fit multi parameters in a given founction form by Python

Tags: python, optimization, parameters, best-fit

I have a function with multi unknown parameters `(m, n, u, v, w, a)`:

```
z=m * (x + 273.15) -n + u * y - v * (x + 273.15)^2 - w * y^2 + a * y * (x + 273.15)
```

and i known some points of `(x, y, z)`, my question is how i can use this to get the best-fit parameters `(m, n, u, v, w, a)` by Python? Thanks!

```
x   y   z
```

400   5   -356383.4277
405 5.2 -355202.4426
410 5.4 -354021.3507
415 5.6 -352840.1520
420 5.8 -351658.8464
425 6   -350477.4341
430 6.2 -349295.9149
435 6.4 -348114.2890
440 6.6 -346932.5562
445 6.8 -345750.7167
450 7   -344568.7703
455 7.2 -343386.7171
460 7.4 -342204.5571
465 7.6 -341022.2904
470 7.8 -339839.9168
475 8   -338657.4364
480 8.2 -337474.8492
485 8.4 -336292.1552
490 8.6 -335109.3543
495 8.8 -333926.4467
500 9   -332743.4323
505 9.2 -331560.3111
510 9.4 -330377.0830
515 9.6 -329193.7482
520 9.8 -328010.3065
525 10  -326826.7581
530 10.2    -325643.1028
535 10.4    -324459.3407
540 10.6    -323275.4719
545 10.8    -322091.4962
550 11  -320907.4137
555 11.2    -319723.2244
560 11.4    -318538.9283
565 11.6    -317354.5254
570 11.8    -316170.0157
575 12  -314985.3991
580 12.2    -313800.6758
585 12.4    -312615.8457
590 12.6    -311430.9088
595 12.8    -310245.8650
600 13  -309060.7145
605 13.2    -307875.4571
610 13.4    -306690.0930
615 13.6    -305504.6220
620 13.8    -304319.0442
625 14  -303133.3596
630 14.2    -301947.5683
635 14.4    -300761.6701
640 14.6    -299575.6651
645 14.8    -298389.5533
650 15  -297203.3347
655 15.2    -296017.0092
660 15.4    -294830.5770
665 15.6    -293644.0380
670 15.8    -292457.3922
675 16  -291270.6395
680 16.2    -290083.7801
685 16.4    -288896.8138
690 16.6    -287709.7408
695 16.8    -286522.5609
700 17  -285335.2742
705 17.2    -284147.8808
710 17.4    -282960.3805
715 17.6    -281772.7734
720 17.8    -280585.0595
725 18  -279397.2388
730 18.2    -278209.3113
735 18.4    -277021.2770
740 18.6    -275833.1359
745 18.8    -274644.8880
750 19  -273456.5332
755 19.2    -272268.0717
760 19.4    -271079.5034
765 19.6    -269890.8282
770 19.8    -268702.0463
775 20  -267513.1575
780 20.2    -266324.1619
785 20.4    -265135.0596
790 20.6    -263945.8504
795 20.8    -262756.5344
800 21  -261567.1116

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have
to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem
with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do these values look reasonable?

```py
[1195.654050550027, 1018.6061701876612, 0.16848387190088943, 3.4621025949581963, 1067.8784835891688, 129.32110722461852]
```

You can play around with different scipy optimizers, or give a better initial value instead of all zeros. There's a small example below.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution

data = """5   400 -356383.4277
5.2 405 -355202.4426
5.4 410 -354021.3507
5.6 415 -352840.152
5.8 420 -351658.8464
..... paste in the full data ...
20.6    790 -263945.8504
20.8    795 -262756.5344
21  800 -261567.1116"""

# Parse data

data = data.split("\n")
data = list(map(lambda x: filter(None, x.split(" ")), data))
data = map(lambda x: list(map(float, x)), data)
data = list(data)

def fn(x, y, m, n, u, v, w, a):
    return m * (x + 273.15) -n + u * y - v * ((x + 273.15) ** 2) - w * (y ** 2) + a * y * (x + 273.15)

def fitness(parameters):
    error = 0
    for y, x, z in data:
        res = fn(x, y, *parameters)
        error += abs(res - z) ** 2
    return error

from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution

# 6 parameters between 0 and 1200
bounds = [(0, 1200)] * 6

x = differential_evolution(fitness, bounds, disp=True).x

print(list(x))

print(fn(795, 20.8, *x))
```

Comment: Dear Yaltirakli, i made a mistake, i just mixed the value of x and y, and i corrected the source data. I got the result [-1440.55868,  5.43178996, 44.3131074, -1.34381584, 1067.97413, 9.17695001] using your python code with initial all zeros value, however, it's much different from the true value [162.29, 474456, 1738, 1.2534e-3, 3.8293, 2.3791e-1], is there a better way to find a good initial value or something i can do? Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Blakelee Please see my edit. I flipped the x and y values and switched to another optimizer. The error is brought down to almost zero and it fits perfectly. Keep in mind that multiple correct solutions are likely possible since there are 6 parameters.

If it still looks wrong, you can check the output of fn manually to see if it makes sense with your values. Maybe that part is the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Could we can utilize it by Matlab? Because i find it could be very slow when dealing with a big data.